# Fedex Freight LTL using active_shipping gem (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

Pretty simple question...does `active_shipping` support Fedex Freight shipments? I've looked and can't seem to find the answer in their documentation.

https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping

If I can be pointed in the right direction I should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the file below in the `active_shipping` source.

**[`lib/active_shipping/shipping/carriers/fedex.rb`](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carriers/fedex.rb#L26-L50)**

It lists multiple `FREIGHT` service types.

```
"FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT" => "FedEx 1 Day Freight",
"FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY" => "FedEx 1 Day Freight Saturday Delivery",
"FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT" => "FedEx 2 Day Freight",
"FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY" => "FedEx 2 Day Freight Saturday Delivery",
"FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT" => "FedEx 3 Day Freight",
"FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY" => "FedEx 3 Day Freight Saturday Delivery",
# ...
"INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_FREIGHT" => "FedEx International Priority Freight",
"INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_FREIGHT" => "FedEx International Economy Freight",
```